C# ASP.NET razor: how to create a moveable shape
I try to understand how to create a diagram in my web. For that, I want to create a shape that can be moved on the screen by the user's mouse.
All what I succeeded to draw is a shape with a text in it, but they don't move. How can I cause them be dragged by mouse?
Thanks,
Haggay

Does JqueryUI Draggable meet the reqirement that you want ?

@TinyWang Yes!!! But I copied the code and it's not being dragged... I see the "Drag me around" rect but cannot drag it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@HaggayF I'm afraid you could press F12 in your browser to see whether there's any error message. And I deduce that the issue is due you missing related JS library. Pls put the js along with Jquery library and you might put them into _layout.cshtml.

Please make sure you have intergrated Jquery into your application. I test with an MVC app, in my cshtml file I have codes below.
<style>
    #draggable {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 1px solid #ccc
    }
</style>
  
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        });
    </script>
}

And in my _Layout_cshtml file, I have codes below. If you want to use corresponding CSS then adding <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> into layout file too.
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)


This worked in my side

